# How to change from laravel 5.4 to laravel 4.2

Tags: javascript, php, html

I tried  with changing composer.json and run the command composer dump-autoload and then composer update ,but it's not working, I have a project using larvel 4.2 so i want to uninstall 5.4 and try with 4.2. and i am new to laravel, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just delete the folder

Comment: eleting will not yield my result, as my project is in 4.2 and i am using 5.4

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/498178/582516

Comment: refer https://askubuntu.com/a/109544/582516

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading To 5.4.0 From 5.3 then refer this  [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade)